# Parse crash reporting not working suddenly

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Parse crash reporting was working before, but from some days its stopped working. I have changed nothing to the Parse crash reporting code. I have below setup for crash reporting.

1. Enabling Crash reporting before setting parse app key and client key

   //Enable Crash reporting Parse

   `[ParseCrashReporting enable];`

   `[Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APPLICATION_KEY
                 clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];`
2. Run script for symbolication

[image: setup in build phases to run symbolication script]

3. Tried crashing forcefully using test crash script provided by parse

   `- (void)crash {
   [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Everything is ok. This is just a test crash."];
   }`

is there any other setup that I am missing ?